# Modification date fields are not up to date in Nemo

Tags: date, nemo, file-metadata

I have a big folder containing several folders.

When I open the big folder in Nemo, I noticed that the modification date of several of the subfolders was not up to date, even if files they contain have been modified recently.

Because of this, sorting the contents of the big folder by the Modification date makes no sense.

Can I force Nemo to update the Modification date fields?

Answer (score 1):

Nemo just displays what the file system tells it. And that, as far as I can tell, it does reliably and correct.

You're misinterpreting the modification time of a directory in UNIX:

That's not the modification time of the most recently modified file inside, it's the last time the directory. Citing `man 7 inode`:

> Moreover, the `mtime` timestamp of a directory is changed by the creation or deletion of files in that directory

So, the modification time of a directory has nothing to do with the modification times of files within!

Hence, sadly:

> Can I force Nemo to update the Modification date fields?

No.